# Scalable NAS: on-premise and minimum of 6 TB

Tags: linux, storage, network-attached-storage

Shying away from the trending cloud storage and hosting a website on an on-premise 6TB storage, what would you recommend for a scalable NAS.
Strictly, the storage solution requires on-premise and minimum of 6TB to host the current data and future-proof for expansion.

Appreciate any leads.

Cheers.

Comment: You might get better answers on the storage email list at http://www.teaparty.net/mailman/listinfo/storage (disclaimer: I host, though do not administer, the list) - not least because it's an on-topic question for that list!

Comment: glusterfs is a good cheap way to set up a scalable distributed file system. There is no support and it will take some effort to build it all initially, but would do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

6TB is not that much data in 2014.

- If you have a lot of money, **[Isilon](http://www.emc.com/domains/isilon/index.htm)**.
- If you want something less than Isilon, but still want support, [**NexentaStor**](http://www.nexenta.com/corp/products/nexentastor) or [**QuantaStor**](http://www.osnexus.com) (both [ZFS-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) on commodity hardware)
- If you want to DIY, Linux on commodity hardware + ZFS (via [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org)).
- If you're old-school, just add direct attached storage shelves to a Linux server. Use standard filesystems and hardware RAID.

Comment: Actualyl 6 TB is 1 disc - so a Raid 1 would work. Granted, it is a little hard to get that one disc - only OEM at the moment. Even when not this is 3 discs (8tb in Raid 5). "Funny" sizes as many end user low end equipment supports that.